# Copy/Paste content of div to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have some div-container with many inputs in it.
I need to copy data from this inputs into another container like first one. Difference - new container has different names and id's for this inputs, so simple `.clone()` not suitable, i think.

Need to copy and past just inputted values.

Is there any other solution then get value from each input and past it to similar input in another container manualy?

Thanks

Example of div:

```
    <div class="listing-space-item-field-row with-label">
        <input id="Spaces_0__SpaceId" name="Spaces[0].SpaceId" value="355637" type="hidden">
        <input class="def-text-input space-name" id="Spaces_0__Name" name="Spaces[0].Name" value="debora" type="text">
        <input class="def-text-input space-size" id="Spaces_0__Size" name="Spaces[0].Size" value="3331" type="text">
        // some other inputs
     </div>
```

Comment: How are the form elements mapped to the different element?

Comment: @epascarello, i have something like editor template (Asp.NET MVC) that renders form for one container. Names are like this `Spaces[0].SpaceName`. When i want to add new Space, i click on button add. And to make it easier(as costumer said) need to populate new container for space with same values as in first container. All Fields have similar classes as `space-name` or `space-prise`

Comment: Can you add a data-attribute to make it simpler?

Comment: @epascarello, so there are any other solution except get values of fields that one by one by data-attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a data attribute you will not need to parse out the common item from the class name attribute. You are going to have to loop through the elements and hide the one that corresponds to it.

```js
$("button").on("click", function () {
  
  var c2 = $("#c2");
  $("#c1 :input").each( function() {
        var elem = $(this);
        var dataItem = elem.data("item"); 
        c2.find('[data-item="' + dataItem + '"]').val(elem.val());
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="c1">
  <select data-item="sel">
      <option>asdf 1</option>
      <option>asdf 2</option>
      <option>asdf 3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" value="a" data-item="one" />
  <input type="text" value="b" data-item="two" />
  <input type="text" value="c" data-item="three" />
</div>
<button>copy</button>
<div id="c2">
  <select data-item="sel">
      <option>asdf 1</option>
      <option>asdf 2</option>
      <option>asdf 3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" value="" data-item="one" />
  <input type="text" value="" data-item="two" />
  <input type="text" value="" data-item="three" />
</div>
```

If the classes are guaranteed and will in the same exact order, you can avoid the data attribute and just look for the same classname.

```
var elem = $(this);
var dataItem = this.className
c2.find('[class="' + dataItem + '"]').val(elem.val());
```

Comment: One question : in `#c1` i have some `select`. When i load page and click on `copy` value from `#c1 select` copied to `#c2 select` fine, but when i change value in `#c1 select` firstly and then click on `copy`, value of `select` in `#c2` is empty. Can you explain me why?

Comment: I just added a select and not seeing that issue. Is it a single select or a multiple select.

Comment: i have JqueryUI select. And also i noticed that if i change any value in input and then make copy, in copy i get value = "" to the similar input

Comment: Well that is not an input element so that is going to have to be handled differently. `c2.find('[data-item="jqs1"]').selectmenu("value", $("#c2").find('[data-item="jqs1"]').selectmenu("value"));` Been awhile since I used JQUI, but I think that is how that works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy `i1` content to `i2`, try:

```
<input id="i1" type="text">
<input id="i2" type="text">
<input type="button" onclick="copy()">
<script>
    function copy() {
        document.getElementById("i2").value = document.getElementById("i1").value;
    }
</script>
```

You can use this as a base if you want to copy several inputs.

Comment: i know about this variant of solution, but i am searching for easiest one. thanks